# Return value of strsplit

Tags: r

In the following example

```
x = strsplit('30 min', ' ')
```

The return value as the docs state is

> A list of the same length as x, the i-th element of which contains the vector of splits of x[i].

I would expect `x[[1]]` to return `30` and `x[[2]]` to return `min`

However `x[[1]][1]` returns `30` and `x[[1]][2]` returns `min`.

What is the explanation for this?

Comment: coming from python, this confused me at first since python has no standard library method to split a lists of strings. Additionally, the docs for strsplit say that x is a character vector, which I read as a single string.

Comment: *A list of the same length as `x`, ...* -- Why would you expect a list of length 2 when `x` is of length 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The explanation is that `strsplit` expects a vector of input strings, each of which will be split into an array of strings, which are returned in the form of a list.
If you only provide this one string, it will be treated like it was the single entry of a vector. Thus, the result is a list with one entry (`x[[1]]`) and it's split contents (`x[[1]][1]` and `x[[1]][2]`), as you've described.

Just use `x <- unlist(strsplit('30 min', ' '))` or `x <- strsplit('30 min', ' ')[[1]]` and you'll get a character-vector, where `x[1]` returns `30` and `x[2]` returns `min`.

Answer (score 5):

The result you get is because you are splitting only one element (this answer expands on comments initially made by [@R. Schifini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1730017/r-schifini)).

```r
x <- '30 min'
length(x)
#> [1] 1
strsplit(x, ' ')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "30"  "min"
```

Try splitting a vector of 3 strings and you'll get a list containing 3 vectors, each containing the split result for a single string.

```r
x <- c( '30 min', '15 min', '20 30 min etc')
length(x)
#> [1] 3
strsplit(x, ' ')
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "30"  "min"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "15"  "min"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "20"  "30"  "min" "etc"
```